# How to create/destroy objects in "modern" C++?

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, memory-management

I am porting C# app into C++ linux app. I am confused with construction and destruction in "modern" (C++11 ?). I always thought you have to use `new/delete` but now it appears C++ recommendation is not to do so (is this correct or I read a wrong blog?).

What I have roughly (there are 6 subclasses of `B` and `BRec` atm):

```
class ARec : public BRec
class A : public B
. . .
class Factory
  BRec GetRecord(WrapperStruct s)
  {
    if(s.Type == 'A')
    {
      A* a = (A*)s.Data;
      auto rec = ARec((ushort)a->Num);
      rec.OtherField = a.OtherField;
      return rec;
    }
. . .
main

// separate pthread
void* Logger(void* arg) {

    int* thread_state = (int*)arg;

    auto f = Factory();

    WrapperStruct item;

    while (true)
    {
      q->try_dequeue(item);

      auto rec = f.GetRecord(item);
      auto bytes = f.GetBytes(rec);

      // write bytes to file ...

      delete bytes;

      if(*thread_state == -1)
        pthread_exit(0);
    }
```

Question - how does compiler would know when to delete `s.Data` in factory method? Same - `rec` if it was created in a class method and then crossed to other method (`while` in Logger)? Is there a simple guide how to manage variables' memory in C++11 ?

**EDIT:** *`s.Data` contains ref to an object created in a 3rd party dll and can be of different types hence the `s.Type` field*

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like in `(A*)s.Data`) you should take that as a sign that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: As for the create/destroy part, just create objects as and when needed (*not* as pointers using `new`, but as actual objects) and then let the object be destructed when their life-time ends. Unless you need polymorphism, in which case you should use smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: `A* a = (A*)s.Data;` this is very C-style, and considered "hacky" in C++. In this piece of code `s.Data` is not deleted anywhere (assuming it was dynamically allocated). The recommendation for modern C++ is not to avoid using new/delete, but to clearly define the dynamic data ownership, which can be done easily with STL containers, smart pointers, etc.

Comment: *I always thought you have to use `new`/`delete`*  In C++, I have not used `new` or `delete` for the last 12 years.  In C++, `std::shared_ptr` is the closest analog to C# reference semantics.  However, that's an object container of last resort, instead `std::unique_ptr` for an owning pointer, and a raw pointer for a non-owning pointer (with care taken for lifetime dependency).  An *automatic storage* object is preferable to *dynamic storage* objects, so using *dynamic storage* is on an as-needed basis.

Comment: I added edit - so how do I write this in non-hacky way?

Comment: You can use `new` and `delete`. It's good to avoid them as much as possible, because when you use `new` and `delete`, you can write bugs. But they're not *forbidden*.

Comment: @BoppityBop, also, try to use `std::thread` instead of pthreads, it would let you pass strongly-typed arguments (including smart pointers!) instead of doing `void*` hackery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart pointers are the key.

```
 std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
 std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar = std::make_unique<Foo>();
```

Shared pointers can be copied. They do reference counting. When the reference count drops to zero, they'll delete their contents automatically.

Unique pointers can't be copied. They can be copied by reference. When the unique pointer goes out of reference, it frees the object for you.

So it works a lot like Java now.

```
 void notAMemoryLeak() {
      std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
 }
```

Other than that, you treat them like pointers. The syntax for their use at this point is identical, except you're passing smart pointers, not Foo *.

```
 void myFunct(std::unique_ptr<Foo> &foo) {
      cout << "Foo: " << foo->getName() << "\n";
 }
```

The `make_shared` and `make_unique` can take the same arguments as any of your Foo's constructors, so feel free to pass stuff.

I do one more thing:

```
 class Foo {
 public:
      typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> Pointer;
      ...
 };

 Foo::Pointer foo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
```

Sometimes I also create static methods to make it even cleaner. This is stylistic and not necessary. Some people might fault me. But it's clean and easy to read.

Comment: Passing a `std::unique_ptr<Foo> &` looks wrong to me, why not just a `Foo*` or `Foo&`? Unless the function operates on the `unique_ptr` as opposed to what it's pointing of course.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR You could do that, too. I tend to use shared_ptrs instead of unique_ptrs.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to me C++ turned into half-managed environment where `std` tries to mimic .net/java (after decades of lamenting them).. good luck with that.